# Negative logic and low-level signal

Tags: digital-logic

Why is negative logic usually associated with low-level signal? If negative logic is just one possible way of achieving results, why do textbooks associate negative logic with low-level signal?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with this question? Can you provide any example of your assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by negative logic you are referring to a 0 in a digital circuit, then it is kind of a tautology. A 0 indicates no-presence of voltage, while a 1 indicates the presence of a voltage.

You could easily flip this notation and everything would still work out. In an and gate you have the inputs A,B and the output C. AB = C works very nicely using a 1 as positive logic since then the truth table simply looks like 1-bit multiplication. However, if you came along and decided that a 0 meant TRUE and a 1 meant FALSE, you would just change the truth table around and everything would still work out.  The truth table would then look like 0 was the multiplicative identity element. For an or gate, the reverse would hold. Currently a 0 is the additive identity element, but if you flipped them then 1 would be the additive identity element.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an arbitrary choice. If you have two states (binary) you need some way of differentiating between them, just like for decimal you need 10 different symbols as opposed to two.

So you pick a system and stick with it, so then everyone knows what is what. It could have been done the other way around, and a logic high been referred to as the "negative" state - this would work fine too, as long as it's consistent.

A good example of this is the actual direction of electron flow and the conventional current flow. By the time we discovered that electrons actually flow from the negative terminal to the positive terminal, the "positive to negative" concept was fixed in everyone's mind so we just carried on with the positive to negative notion.

As long as you have a reference point, and to have a consistent system that works relative to it, then it doesn't matter - the maths works out the same way.

You could say that maybe 0 resembled "O" for "off", or 0V, so this was chosen as the negative/low logic level.

Comment: ECL, an old logic family, used a negative power supply, and a low voltage (that is, close to zero) represented a logic 1, while a more negative voltage (closer to the supply voltage) represented a 0. Kind of the opposite of what is common with TTL and all its siblings (if you ignore the fact that the supply voltage was negative).

Comment: @Wouter - yes, ECL is a nice example of (a very fast IIRC) way of doing things the other way round. Then there's PECL, it's positive relative. There are so many standards nowadays (especially with FPGAs) I lose track.